# How is it possible to memoize longest divisible subset using only the length (and end position)?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

The goal is to find the largest divisible subset. A divisible subset is a subset s.t. for every pair of elements i, j, either i is divisible by j or j is divisible by i. The general approach to solve this is to sort the numbers and realize that if a is divisible by b and b by c, that a must also be divisible by c. Here's the unmemoized recursion:

```
def largestDivisibleSubset0(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    def backtrack(candidate, end):
        if len(candidate) > len(self.best):
            self.best = candidate[:]

        if end == n - 1:
            return

        for new_end in range(end+1, n):
            if not candidate or candidate[-1] % nums[new_end] == 0:
                backtrack(candidate+[nums[new_end]], new_end)

    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    n = len(nums)
    self.best = []
    backtrack([], -1)
    return self.best
```

Next, I tried to memoize. Forgive the poor style where `self.best` and memo are both tracked. I know it's redundant and that I'm not actually caching the local best but instead the global (side question: what *is* the best way to memoize this?)

```
def largestDivisibleSubset(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    def backtrack(candidate, end):
        if (len(candidate), end) in memo:
            return memo[(len(candidate), end)]

        if len(candidate) > len(self.best):
            self.best = candidate[:]

        if end == n - 1:
            return

        for new_end in range(end+1, n):
            if not candidate or candidate[-1] % nums[new_end] == 0:
                backtrack(candidate+[nums[new_end]], new_end)

        memo[(len(candidate), end)] = self.best

    nums.sort(reverse=True)
    n = len(nums)
    self.best = []
    memo = {}
    backtrack([], -1)
    return self.best
```

Here's what I don't understand. How is it an accurate representation of the state to simply consider the length of the current candidate, and not the last element? What if a subsequence ending in 5 has length x, equal to a subsequence ending in 4 — isn't it possible the latter one gets pruned from the search space, even if it might result in a longer divisible subset down the line?

Comment: What does your `end` parameter mean?

Comment: End is the current position being considered to include or not. When end = x, only the first x characters have been considered

Comment: The current one? Shouldn't it try `range(end, n)` then instead of `range(end+1, n)`?

Comment: you need range(end+1, n) or you'd just be repeating the same index again

Comment: So what does `end` really tell you?

Comment: end is how this is DP. it breaks down the problem into subproblems. end allows you to say, up to an ending index, what is the longest divisible subset

Comment: Ok I give up...

Comment: Note that this problem is a particular case of [longest path in a directed acyclic graph](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=longest+path+in+a+dag)

Answer (score 0):

`end` tells you the candidate subsequence ending.

> What if a subsequence ending in 5 has length x, equal to a subsequence ending in 4

Then their `end` differs and thus their memo key differs and thus they don't prune each other.

Comment: Nah this isn't correct. End is not the last index that was used, it's the last index we've considered. If we've considered up to x elements, a length of 1 could represent any of the x elements

Comment: @Alec See your call: `backtrack(candidate+[nums[new_end]], new_end)`. The same value `new_end` is used for both the `candidate`'s last element and the `end` value.